# unbind is not function - jQuery validation error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery form that doesn't submit until is passes a validation (I'm new learner) but I am getting this error from the console: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unbind is not a function

```
    $("form").submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var error = "";

        //MY VALIDATION CODE HERE

        if(error != "") {

            $("#error").html('Please check the following error(s)' + error);

        } else {

            $("form").unbind("submit").submit(); <<< CONSOLE ERROR HERE

        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this will be a matter of jQuery version. If you're using Rob Percival's CompleteWebDev course, the video has not been updated (at the time of this writing) to troubleshoot this.

The .bind/.unbind are now obsolete and you should be using .on/.off at the time of my writing.

Use the code below and it should work now:

$("form").off("submit").submit();

Answer (score 0):

My code wasn't working and later I learnt that jQuery .bind/.unbind methods are deprecated and to solve that I moved `e.preventDefault();` inside the IF so I will not call it unless the validation failed then I removed the whole unbind part.

Answer (score 0):

We can also avoid using e.preventDefault(); or $("form").off("submit").submit(); by returning true and false;

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$("form").submit(function (e){

    // e.preventDefault();//jQuery, it prevent the default action of the event

    var error = "";

    if($("#email").val() == ""){
        error += "The email field is required.<br>";
    }

    if($("#subject").val() == ""){
        error += "The subject field is required.<br>";
    }

    if($("#content").val() == ""){
        error += "The content field is required.";
    }

    if(error != ""){

        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' +
                    '<p><strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong></p>'+ error +
        '</div>');

        return false;

    }else{
        return true;
    }



});
```